# Virtual properties in out of sequence policies

Tags: guidewire

We have couple of Virtual properties in the vehicle enhancement class. These properties are sent as part of the payload xml from the PolicyPeriodRootModel.gx to the document system. These values are sent properly for normal transactions. However, for Out of sequence transactions these virtual properties are not appended in the policyperiod root object and the values are not passing in the payoad. Is there any workaround for this? to append the values to the policyperiod root object?

Comment: yes, it is possible. add Virtual property in Vehicle enhancement, and add-in GX. now,  u can see those fields in the payload.

Comment: Shiva, those properties are already there in Vehicle Enhancement. It is coming in the payload. But for Out of sequence transactions it is not coming.

Comment: maybe for OOS, those fields are null. Null fields won't build in the payload or maybe logic is stoping for building.

Comment: What are those Virtual properties ? Is it OOTB properties ?

Comment: No those are not OOTB properties. They are customized Virrtual properties to calculate vehicle premium like Net premium, Tax, gst etc

Comment: Also during the OOS transaction, we will get an option to override all changes to future policyperiods. Check what you have selected ? And see the code logic whether you are populating with enough data in Table to derive the values for the virtual properties..

Comment: @ArunKumarMani i tried investigating that part. However, the variable "*policyPeriod" during the startChange.pcf itself does not have these values for the virtual properties for an OOS transaction. i.e during the start of policychange wizard.  This variable stores values during normal transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying access to an EffDated entity (PolicyPeriod, PersonalVehicle by example) in Window mode, not in at Slice mode. Check your logic to ensure that get first a slice.